# Difference between 10.0.19041 and 10.0.22000 SDK

Tags: windows, sdk, visual-studio-2022

while understanding the differences between 10.0.19041.0 and 10.0.22000.0 SDK ,I encountered
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/ this page. After looking into it , I understood 10.0.22000.0 is mainly for windows 11 applications .

If we select 10.0.019041 as the package and build the application, won't it run on windows 11.

If we want our application to be run on windows 11 do  we need to choose 10.0.22000.0 over 10.0.19041.0.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10):

TLDR: No, your understanding is wrong. You can likely use whatever version you want and your application will run on both, Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Long with details:

1. It's true, the 10.0.19041 SDK is for Windows 10.
2. It's also true, 10.0.22000 SDK is for Windows 11.

Let's have a look from a **user perspective**:

When you download software, how often do you need to select the correct operating system? Not very often. So, somehow, the SDK version does not seem to be very important.

Let's have a look from a **Microsoft perspective**:

Does Microsoft want all developers require a rebuild of their Windows 10 programs once they release Windows 11? Certainly not, because this would mean that with the release of Windows 11, there wouldn't be a single application which runs on Windows 11. Microsoft couldn't even perform inhouse tests for multi-million-user software such as Adobe Reader.

Let's have a look from a **technical perspective**:

The Windows SDK provides the API definitions of Windows. The Windows API is very old. And since Microsoft does not want developers to rebuild and, even worse, let them fix breaking changes, Microsoft keeps that API incredibly stable. They will not change the API, they will only add new API methods.

The chance that the Windows API **you use** already existed in Windows 10 and still exists in Windows 11 is almost 100%. So your application compiled for Windows 10 will still work on Windows 11.

Likewise, if you compile with the Windows 11 API and don't use the most recent fancy API, your application will still work on Windows 10.

**Example**

Let's say you developed an application that manages Fonts. You have used the interfaces `IDWriteFontSet`, `IDWriteFontSet2` and `IDWriteFontSet3`. With Windows 11, Microsoft has added `IDWriteFontSet4`. As long as you don't use that interface and stick to the previous 3 interfaces, your application will run fine. Once you start using `IDWriteFontSet4`, your application may crash on Windows 10 (potentially only if the user invokes the functionality, not so sure).